# React+Redux+Asynch: data loading cascade, start the following after the previous complete

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, react-redux, fetch-api

Having not much experience in ReactJS currently trying to solve components cascade loading. Let me explain use case on an example.

[image: After AUthor data is fetched from backend -> select 1st found element -> start search athour's books -> select the 1st found book -> start search library by the author and the book]

Assume we have 3 comboboxes - Author, Book, Library.
Something triggers loading Author data -> When data is loaded, the first found author is automatically selected and is used as search criteria for the second combobox(Book) -> When all books of the selected Author is loaded, the first found book is selected. The selected Author and Book are used as search criteria for the 3rd combobox(Library) - after library is found select the first in the list.

- Data is loaded using '[cross-fetch](https://github.com/lquixada/cross-fetch)'.
- Internal component is built from 3 "Select"(comboboxes) controls. Initially, an internal
  implementation of 'Select' React control is used but the flow was
  checked with [react-select](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/) library as well. In both cases the
  initialization of comboboxes looks similar:

  ```
  <Select
    options={authors}
    value={selectedAuthor}
    onChange={this._authorChanged}
  />
  ```
- react-redux#connect maps state to props

So the questions is:
how properly and what is a proper place to catch "data loading is complete" events so that the next planning loadings may be initiated?

What I did/thought about:

1. I can detect in **render()** method that it is time to start the following data loading but as I learned it is not a good solution(we better not to do any operations other than required for rendering inside the method).
2. Theoretically, I can build loading chain from my actions but at the moment I do not like the idea as:

   - despite load method is currently used only for the initializaion of combobox later I want to reuse it in other places where next loading is not needed;
   - currently for me this does not look consistent when data load is not fired by  ui events
3. I thought setting default selected value **value={selectedAuthor}** 
   during initialization would fire **onChange** event but it seems not true(at least in my case).

Comment: lets assume you have a reducer to store those 3 lists like authors, books, libraries. You will need another 3 object to retain selected options of those 3 lists. Then on first loading you fetch authors that will fill your list. These will go in to the select and trigger onChange that will store the option and with this option will trigger book fetch. Same procedure for everything will solve this

Comment: I do have objects - 3 lists and 3 objects to store selection.
The problem is that onChange is not triggered when I set data in render() method by:
`<Select
          options={authors}
          value={selectedAuthor}
          onChange={this._authorChanged}
        />`.
 But the event onChange is triggered when selection is changed manually.

Comment: Thats correct add an option before your map on the list eg on authors options to say “select authors”. Then on user select will do what you want. Otherwise you must chain the api calls but in this case you don’t know what author for example to select. Third option is to fetch all the data. Like you will have authors with all the other data inside it as an object and filter it

Comment: Thanks Panagiotis for your time and responses! Finally I stopped on using `componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps)` method. Having the current props values and the following ones it is easy to detect if the next loadings are good to initiate.
But actually `componentWillReceiveProps` is already a legacy method and needs to be replaced; more detailed information is provided on [Update on Async Rendering](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/03/27/update-on-async-rendering.html) by Brian Vaughn